# How to calculate mutual elements between two 2D arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, checksum

I have 2D arrays, I want to compare

```
['A','E','C','G', 'T'] & ['A','C','E','N','M']
['a','f','b','c','u'] & ['a','b','c','y','l']
```

and calculate the same elements (regardless of the order of the elements).

```
aaa = [['A','E','C','G','T'],['a','f','b','c','u']]
bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M'],['a','b','c','y','l']]
```

So in this example, the output is `6(3+3)`

I tried:

```
c = sum(ii[0] == ii[1] for i in zip(aaa, bbb) for ii in zip(*i))
print(c)
```

but the output is `2 (1+1)`

Comment: Python has `set`s with set-operations.

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
set1 = set(['A','E','C','G', 'T']) 
set2 =  set(['A','C','E','N','M'])
common_elements = set1.intersection(set2)
print(common_elements)
print('Number of common elements is: {}'.format(len(common_elements)))
```

output

```
{'A', 'C', 'E'}
Number of common elements is: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
sum(len(set(ai) & set(bi)) for ai, bi in zip(aaa, bbb))
```

This will convert the elementwise sublists to sets and calculate the number of elements in the intersection.

For example:

```
>>> sum(len(set(ai) & set(bi)) for ai, bi in zip(aaa, bbb))
6
```